# Devise : Override confirmations so users can pick their own passwords as part of confirmation activation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I’m tying to get devise confirmable email to activate account, the email gets send, when I got to the link to confirm the account, I then enter passwords, passwords gets encrypted and redirected to root. But I get then a notice saying “ You need to activate your account first.. ”  or some thing like that.

What I'm trying to do is to have an admin user creating users by adding email address, and then the users receive an email to activate there account and enter there password and for that [I was following this instructions](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Override-confirmations-so-users-can-pick-their-own-passwords-as-part-of-confirmation-activation)

**User Model**

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
       :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable,
       :token_authenticatable, :confirmable, :validatable
```

**ConfirmationsController**

the rest of the controller is the same as on [Devise Wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Override-confirmations-so-users-can-pick-their-own-passwords-as-part-of-confirmation-activation)

```
def update
    with_unconfirmed_confirmable do
      if @confirmable.has_no_password?
        @confirmable.attempt_set_password(params[:user])
        if @confirmable.valid?
          do_confirm
        else
          do_show
          @confirmable.errors.clear #so that we wont render :new
        end
      else
        self.class.add_error_on(self, :email, :password_allready_set)
      end
    end

    if !@confirmable.errors.empty?
      render 'devise/confirmations/new' #Change this if you don't have the views on default path
    end
  end

  protected

  def with_unconfirmed_confirmable
    original_token = params[:confirmation_token]
    confirmation_token = Devise.token_generator.digest(User, :confirmation_token, original_token)
    @confirmable = User.find_or_initialize_with_error_by(:confirmation_token, confirmation_token)
    if !@confirmable.new_record?
      @confirmable.only_if_unconfirmed {yield}
    end
  end

 def do_confirm
    @confirmable.confirm!
    set_flash_message :notice, :confirmed
    sign_in(:user, @confirmable)
    redirect_to(root_path)
  end
```

Also user :confirmed_at column dose not get updated, and I also can't update it in the console.

> The problem really is the user record dose not get confirmed when user
>   follow the email link enter passwords, but the record get updated and
>   password set..

If I try to sign in anyway I get the following :

```
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 3 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 3ms
```

But I think this is because the user record is not confirmed.

Any idea...?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so the problem was, for some reason I have added `attr_accessor :confirmed_at` in the User Model, that was overwriting devise's update :confirmed_at.